# Retrieving featured entry from a given category

Tags: templating, lightswitch

This piece of code used to work to retrieve 1 featured (lightswitch) entry per category.

```
{% for category in craft.categories %}      
    {% set entries = craft.entries.find({
      section:    'news',
      limit:      '1',
      featured : '1',
      search :"category:" ~ category.title,
      order :'postDate desc'
    }) %}
```

Somehow I have to save a entry twice now before it appears. Any ideas whats wrong? Is this a craft bug?

Answer (score 4):

<del>There’s currently a bug with storing keywords based on related elements, which we’re looking into.</del> Using the `search` parameter for this isn’t really the right way to go anyway, though.

Instead you should be using the [`relatedTo` param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.find({
    section:   'news',
    limit:     1,
    featured:  1,
    relatedTo: { targetElement: category, field: 'category' },
    order:     'postDate desc'
}) %}
```

**UPDATE**

The aforementioned bug was fixed in [Craft 2.1.2563](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2563).  You’re still better off using the `relatedTo` param though.

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed a typo in the above code block.